# With Procedure for a beginner so far i've come alone but i can't understand where i'm going wrong

Tags: sql-server, procedure

How do I solve it? the idea is to insert the records of the table people, phone and address at once, but each one with its data and respecting the ID created by the identity in the table people replicated in the others in the field people_id

```
Create Procedure newRegister
(
    @PeopleID int,
    @Name nvarchar(100),
    @Phone numeric(9),
    @Adress nvarchar(150),
    @NumLocal numeric(5),
    @Type_Fone nvarchar(20),
    @CodeArea numeric (3)
)

AS 

begin
INSERT INTO people values (@Name, @Phone,@Adress)
INSERT INTO adress values (@Adress,@PeopleID)
INSERT INTO phones values (@Phone,@CodeArea,@Type_Fone,@PeopleID)
end
```

**on Exec:**

```
exec newRegister @PeopleID = 1, @Name = "Victor", @Phone = 111222333, @Adress = 'Northen Street 55', @NumLocal = 155, @Type_Fone = 'Mobile', @CodeArea = 100
```

After execute, only the person table receives the data, the address table has a foreign key violation error, and the phone table also has the same error.
and data is not entered.

**My table people**

```
CREATE TABLE people (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    name nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    adress nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    phone numeric(9) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**my table phone:**

```
CREATE TABLE phone (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    phone numeric(9) NOT NULL,
    codearea numeric(3) NOT NULL,
    type_fone nvarchar(20) NOT NULL,
    people_id int NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
     CONSTRAINT FK_phone_people FOREIGN KEY (people_id)
    REFERENCES people(id)
);
```

**my table adress:**

```
CREATE TABLE adress (
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    adress nvarchar(150) NOT NULL,
    numlocal numeric(5) NOT NULL,
    people_id int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
     CONSTRAINT FK_adress FOREIGN KEY (people_id)
    REFERENCES people(id)
);
```

Comment: A "phone number" is not a number: it is a string which contains mostly digits, and leading zeros need to be preserved. Also, please spell *address* correctly.

Comment: right just one example the inserts are working the error just occurs in the foreign key.

Comment: Why are you passing in the value for @PeopleID if that is supposed to be the value of the identity column in the people table? You should insert that data and then use scope_identity()

Comment: Also, why are you not specifying the columns in your insert statement? The order of columns in your provided table do not match the order of provided parameters to the insert statement. And in the "adress" table you don't even have enough values for all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the fields

FROM

```
begin
INSERT INTO people values (@Name, @Phone,@Adress)
INSERT INTO adress values (@Adress,@PeopleID)
INSERT INTO phones values (@Phone,@CodeArea,@Type_Fone,@PeopleID)
end
```

TO

```
--Example, btw address, not adress if You are going for English
INSERT INTO PEOPLE(name, phone, adress)
VALUES(@Name, @Phone,@Adress)
```